# backbone: rendering tree data and updating on changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I get from server some kind of tree data (just for the example):

```
[
    {
    nodeName: "top level 1",
    nodes: [
        {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 1",
        nodes: [
            {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 1"}
        ]}
    ]},
{
    nodeName: "top level 2",
    nodes: [
        {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 3",
        nodes: [
            {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 7"},
        {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 8"},
        {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 9"}
        ]}
    ]}
]​
```

To render this I'am using Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView & Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
http://jsfiddle.net/AdWjU/179/ (following [derickbailey's article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)).

But I need to poll server every 300 seconds and it can return changed tree:

```
[
    {
    nodeName: "top level 1",
    nodes: [
        {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 1",
        nodes: [
            {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 1"},
            {
            nodeName: "new name"} // changed
        ]}
    ]},
{
    nodeName: "top level 2",
    nodes: [
        {
        nodeName: "2nd level, item 3",
        nodes: [
            {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 7"},
        {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 8"},
        {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 9"},
        {
            nodeName: "3rd level, item 10"} // added
        ]}
    ]}
]​
```

Now I simply call tree.update(data) to rerender entire data.

How can I update only views which depend on changed properties?

I'm trying to reduce views which be rerendered. Should I go with CompositeViews or try something like Backbone-relational model to accomplish this task?

Comment: feel free to accept the answer or ask for a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're rebuilding the collection every time on initialize, you're blasting away and recreating your node tree from scratch whenever you call `update`.

In order to preserve your node tree, you have to synchronize the tree you get from the server in backbone. Most straightforward way to do that is to create unique ids that are passed along with nodeName, and base your models and collections off of that. Then you can rewrite this:

```
if (nodes) {
  this.nodes = new TreeNodeCollection(nodes);
  this.unset("nodes");
}
```

To do a lookup to see if your node exists and append to the relevant collection instead of blasting it out and recreating.